# How to add a constraint programmatically so that the height of a view just fits the bottom of its last subview?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have constraint code that lays out a number of UILabels (4+) vertically from top to bottom inside a container view (a regular `UIView`). I now want my container view to be sized so that its height matches the bottom of that last label that I've added.

I have tried this:

```
let constraintPanelHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.panelOptions, 
    attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: priorLabel!, 
    attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
cell.contentView.addConstraint(constraintPanelHeight)
```

but this generates an `Invalid pairing of layout attributes` error since I'm matching .Height of one view with .Bottom of a subview (I'm guess that's why).

How can I auto-size my containing view like this?

Comment: Why not just set the superview's bottom to be equal to the last subview's bottom? That is, don't concern yourself with the height.

Comment: @Ken: your suggestion is in the ballpark, but it not working exactly since I'm matching the bottom of the container to the bottom of its last subview (which is a subview, of course) - so it picks up additional height equal to whatever its .top is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your trying to achieve there exactly. If you want to pin the one cell to the bottom of the other, you'll have to use attribute `.Top` and another constraint for the height. For example: you have 10 labels in your view, then set your height to one tenth of the superview:

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.panelOptions, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0)
```

But since iOS9 there's also the `UIStackView` which makes laying out subviews in a view (vertically or horizontally) very easy. Have a look at that if you want to spread your labels evenly in your superview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fixed number of views the easiest and most readable way is the use the visual layout format and constraints like this:
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints

```
WithVisualFormat("V:|[view1][view2][view3]|",
  options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX,
  metrics: nil,
  views: ["view1": view1, "view2": view2,"view3": view3])
```

If you want to add a variable number the principle is the same but achieved with a loop. You shouldn't set the height of anything. Let the intrinsicContentSize of each label size the container from the inside. You might need to set the priority of contentCompressionResistance of each label to 1000 just to be sure the labels don't get squashed. Keep in mind the you will need horizontal constraints as well but they should be simpler to work out.

And here's the version for a variable number of subviews:

```
var prevView : UIView?
for view in views{
  container.addSubview(view)
  //
  // Add horizontal constraints for each view to fit the container
  // exclude for simplicity

  // Add vertical constraints
  if prevView == nil{
    container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: container,
      attribute: .Top,
      relatedBy: .Equal,
      toItem: view,
      attribute: .Top,
      multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    )
  } else if view == views.last!{
    container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: container,
      attribute: .Bottom,
      relatedBy: .Equal,
      toItem: view,
      attribute: .Bottom,
      multiplier: 1,
      constant: 0))
  } else if let prev = prevView {
    container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: prev,
      attribute: .Bottom,
      relatedBy: .Equal,
      toItem: view,
      attribute: .Top,
      multiplier: 1,
      constant: 0))
  }
  prevView = view
}
```